# 206 partial content mp4 in angular 7 html

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to load the video in `HTML` in video source `HTML` tag from assets folder in `angular 7` but when I load the page it's giving `"206 partial content mp4"` error and video is no load.

````
  ```
  <div class="video_mask">
    <video id="click" width="100%" height="100%" poster="assets/img/video.png">
      <source src="assets/img/compress_Sportlo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
````

Answer (score 0):

try to change this settings in angular.json

```
 "budgets": [
        {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "2mb",
          "maximumError": "30mb"  <<< default is 5mb
        }
      ]
```

Comment: It is better to give some explanation of the solution than just give code.

Comment: No, that's assuming that the video was not bundled.